# Android Widevine HLS/DRM support

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, http-live-streaming, drm

It will be soon 2 years since Google acquires the Widevine company that provides the DRM support for protecting e.g. the HLS H.264/AAC streams.

According to the http://www.widevine.com/ not only Android, but also iPhone/iPad and game consoles like Wii or PS3 ares supported.

Does anybody experience with the Android Widevine DRM?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must be certified by google to work with the Widevine APIs.
the certification is called CWIP and requires paying a substantial sum and going through a course.

Comment: Hi, we already know that:)) We are using the Widevine and PlayReady DRM as SaaS, so we do not need to be CWIP...

Comment: And for GoogleTV and all SmartTVs you do not need to be a CWIP for client development. However using Widevine on Android is pretty hard due to fragmentation.