# WideVine tvOS support

Tags: tvos, drm, widevine

Please guide me through this if someone has already worked on tvOS. Currently I am porting ios app to tvOS. But need to know if widevine supports tvOS? And what are the points as this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350245/android-widevine-hls-drm-support/41339857#41339857](http://widevine%20support)

says that developers who is trying to develop for smart TV does not need to to go through CWIP. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: After so many mails from google and so many weeks after executing agreement with them ,they(Google) have confirmed that Widevine does not support Apple TV (tvOS). Posting it ,so others could learn from this and hope it would help them deciding about DRM services.